# do i need to mock all dependencies from a angularjs controller in a unit test?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

i have a controller with multiple dependencies.
do i need to mock it all to test my scope?
this is my code....

```
.controller('SignupCtrl', ['$scope', 'vcRecaptchaService', '$http', '$location', '$compile', 'createModal', '$routeParams',
        '$filter', 'allCountriesService', 'allStatesProvincesService', 'allCitiesMunicipalitiesService', 'appConfig', 'AuthService',
        '$rootScope', '$timeout', 'appConfigHC', '$log',
        function ($scope, vcRecaptchaService, $http, $location, $compile, $createModalService, $routeParams, $filter, allCountriesService, allStatesProvincesService, allCitiesMunicipalitiesService, appConfig, AuthService, $rootScope, $timeout, appConfigHC, $log) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You should only need to mock the dependencies that have `$http` calls to the server.  The rest of the dependencies that just contain logic that resides entirely in JavaScript should not need to be mocked.

Here is a link that explains more about using `$httpBackend` which is used to mock calls to the server.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Create a service which handles all  http calls for you and mock that service. Handling http calls in a controller is not recommended.

Comment: Sorry I meant to say inside a controller is not recommended

Comment: Please edit your answer instead of adding a comment.